# Windows 10 keeps reinstalling USB drivers at boot

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I'm not actually sure Windows is "reinstalling" the drives, but you know when you connect a new USB device, there are two things that happen:

1. You get the "installing device drives" message.
2. You hear that newly connected device Windows "sound" and get the "Device has been successfully connected and is ready for use" message

Well, my Windows 10 runs smoothly with no issues, and no yellow warnings in device manager but every time I restart, all of my connected USB devices will not work for a few seconds (including the mouse) and during boot, it will make that "connected new device sound" and popup the "Device has been successfully connected and is ready for use" messages - 10 times (for each of the 10 USB devices I have connected to the computer).

It's not affecting my work because I don't restart often but it's annoying and I don't understand why it's happening.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

The system logs say "Successfully attached to device \Device\HarddiskVolume15" on each USB device at reboot.

[image]

Comment: Questions: (1) What is your motherboard and computer model? (2) Does the problem arrive if you have less devices connected? (3) How many of the devices draw power from the computer? (4) Which Power Options plan you are using? (5) Does the BIOS has "Legacy USB Support" as On and does it help to turn it off? (6) Is your BIOS the latest version from the motherboard vendor's website? (7) Try the Windows USB troubleshooter.

Comment: (1) MB: GA-Z77X-UP4 TH, CPU: Intel i7 3770k (2) I can't check that. I have over 20 devices and Synology network raid disks connected and can't disconnect them. Never had this issue with them for the past 15 years. (3) Only 3. Mouse, keyboard and a snowball microphone. (4) Manually configured for best optimization (so usb devices don't turn off ever and computer never sleeps) (5) Yes, it's always on. didn't check with it off (6) Yes, I flashed to latest version like a year ago and it's still latest version (7) Doubt it but I'll try

Comment: Have any USB device drivers changed at about the time this happened? Try in *Devices and Printers*, right-click your computer, *Device Installation Settings*, set to "No" and *Save Changes*, then reboot.

Comment: No new drivers were updated as far as I can tell. I tried what you said but it didn't solve it - but that was a great thought strategy!

Comment: I added an UPDATE to the question about what I saw in the system logs at reboot. Maybe this will help figure this out.

Comment: What type of USB device are you dealing with?  If it's removable storage it absolutely is normal for it to generate the event in question.

Comment: Yes, they are removable but this question has 89 views and a 50 point bounty. Don't you think if this is normal behavior in Windows 10 that someone would have posted that as an answer by now?

Comment: Yes, this is uncommon behavior. One more test: Try booting into Safe Mode and then rebooting again into the same Safe Mode, to see if this happens for one or both reboots or none. Useful tool is [msconfig](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-start-windows-in-safe-mode-using-system-configuration-2626115).

Comment: Sorry for not updating. Yes, I tried this morning. When booting into safe mode, only the MOUSE makes a "connected" sound and then it's light turns on (can't use the mouse before that) but all other external drives are ok. (rebooted to SM twice like you said). But when then booting regular, same issue.

Comment: If the other devices than the mouse still worked without these error messages arriving for them during the boot, this sounds like a problem with an installed product. I suggest to (1) Run `chkdsk`, (2) Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html), (3) Use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) turn off/on startup products in bunches to find one that causes this problem, rebooting each time.

Comment: Didn 't help. Also disabled EVERY startup item except for essential ones to Windows. This only started happening when I installed Windows 10. It wasn't a clean install but installed over Win 7 Ultimate while keeping programs. Maybe it has to do with that and there's nothing to do about it until I make a clean Windows install, which I won't be doing anytime soon. Thank you so much for your help. I don't mind giving you the bounty points for your troubles but I don't think I can if there is no accepted answer.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the poster that the problem is too weird to be found and is perhaps
not worth the trouble, when a fresh install of Windows 10 would probably fix
the problem.

This problem is probably due to a botched upgrade from Windows 7.
I suspected that it may relate to some installed product, but since booting in
Safe mode does not abolish all the messages, and even in that mode
the message still arrives for the mouse, I think that this does not seem likely.

There is a problem then with Windows itself, rare enough that similar cases
cannot be found, although I did search for them.

My recommendation is to reinstall Windows 10. You do not need a serial number
for that, since your digital entitlement is already registered with Microsoft.
I would only counsel ensuring that you have all the required drivers for the
computer before starting.

It would also be a good idea to take an image backup of the system drive
before starting, not using Windows Backup but a third-party one such as
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html),
and creating its
[Bootable CD](https://www.backup-utility.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html)
and verifying that it can boot and can access the backup image, in case you need
to go back to the current installation.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this problem tonight and stumbled on this question while looking for advice. I'm running win11 pro, but the same issue was happening. What i found was that I had a bootable drive installed. I wasn't booting to it but it was there and after I ejected that bootable recovery usb drive and restarted the pc, the problem was solved. All "normal" USB storage devices acted normal in that I didn't not receive popups as if I had just plugged them in.